# Does Kotlin has a scope delimiter?

Tags: scope, kotlin

In C one can use **{** and **}** as a scope delimiter.

For example:

```
int myfunc()
{
    int i = 4;

    {
        int j = 5;
        i = i + j;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In this example the **{** and **}** create a new scope and so the **j** can't be seen outside of the **{** and **}**.

Does Kotlin supports this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to @zsmb13's answer, you may look into scoping functions ([Standard.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt)). The idiomatic way of creating a scope in Kotlin would be:

```
var i = 0
run {
  i++
}
println(i)
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't, because this syntax creates a lambda expression (which then isn't assigned to anything, and is never called).

So this code does nothing to the initial value of `i`:

```
var i = 0
{
    i++
}
println(i) // 0
```

You can however assign the lambda to a variable and call it:

```
var i = 0
val f: () -> Int = { 
    i++ 
}
f()
println(i) // 1
```

Or invoke it immediately in a JavaScript-ish style, which might be frowned upon by some people:

```
var i = 0
{
    i++
}()
println(i) // 1
```